# Minor suggestion for the FAQ on SO (and probably other trilogy sites)

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Under "What is Reputation", it should mention that if you amass 100 points, you can offer a bounty. (Note: it does say this later in the section discussing bounties, but it would be nice if all features that become available as you amass points were listed in one place.)